# Is it possible to retrieve gin Context anywhere in the code (GoLang)?

Tags: go, go-gin

I know in Java Springboot, it is possible to call SecurityContext anywhere in the code to get the context.

For example:

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
```

My question is, is it possible to get the `*gin.Context` anywhere in the code without having to pass it as a parameter to my function?

Answer (score 0):

Golang has another package called `"context"` which does not depend on `"gin"`. You can use `context.Background()` anywhere in your code:

```
import (
    "context"
)

...
// sample usage for Mongodb 
// operation which requires context

resp, err := client.collection.InsertOne(
        context.Background(), // here
        ...,
)
...
```